# The last digit of number $2^{100}+5^{100}+8^{100}$ is

Tags: number-theory

I don't really know how to exactly solve this problem, is there a method?

Comment: Hint: can you do the computations modulo 10?

Comment: Try with a few small n of those powers, and you'll find they are cyclical

Comment: $n^5-n$ is divisible by $10.$  Which means that the last digit of n^5 has the same last digit as $n.$  Using this knowledge, can you reduce the order of those exponents?

Comment: Sure @DougM that seems a nice method to try on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2 \mod 10 = 2, \qquad 2^2 \mod 10 = 4, \qquad 2^3 \mod 10 = 8, \qquad 2^4 \mod 10 = 6$

Then the pattern repeats.

---

$5^k \mod 10 = 5$ for all positive integers $k$.

---

$8 \mod 10 = 8, \qquad 8^2 \mod 10 = 4, \qquad 8^3 \mod 10 = 2, \qquad 8^4 \mod 10 = 6$

Then the pattern repeats.

---

Now put all this together with the fact that $(a+b+c) \mod 10 = [(a \mod 10) + (b \mod 10) + (c \mod 10)] \mod 10$.

Comment: Why did you choose 10 for modulo?

Comment: @ltishree: It is because our number system is in base $10$, so all numbers can be written in the form $10^n a + 10^{n-1} b+ ... + 10c + d $, so modulo $10$ gives $d \space (\mod 10)$. I.e. the last digit.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @infinitylord

Answer (score 1):

- The last digit of $2^n$ is periodic with period $4$ i.e. last digit of $2^{r+4}$ is same as last digit of $2^r (r>0)$
- Last digit of $5^n$ is always $5$
- Rewrite $8^m$ in terms of power of $2$ as $2^{3m}$